# Alternative Basemap scalebar with projection='cyl'

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html
Based on this documentation for the Basemap function "drawmapscale," we know that we cannot use it for the default cylindrical mapping coordinate system (projection = 'cyl' is the argument). So I was wondering, what are the alternative scalebar options that one could use without changing from projection = 'cyl'. Here is my Basemap for reference:

```
lat_max = 38.5
lat_min = 34.5
lon_min = -123.0
lon_max = -117.5

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lon_min,llcrnrlat=lat_min,urcrnrlon=lon_max,
    urcrnrlat=lat_max,projection='cyl',resolution='i')
```